# What is the back channel logout url for a Keycloak used as an Identity Broker?

Tags: keycloak

We use Keycloak as an Identity Broker which delegates user authentication to an external Identity Provider.

This external Identity Provider needs the back channel logout url of Keycloak to end user session on this Keycloak when user logout from this external Identity provider.

I didn't see where I can find it in Keycloak admin interface or in Keycloak OpenID Endpoint Configuration.

It's not the "end_session_endpoint" because this is used for front channel logout (with browser interaction) not for a back channel call that doesn't involve a browser.

This is our configuration: MyApp -> MyKeycloak -> ExternalIDP

- MyKeycloak : my keycloak instance
- MyApp : a web application, configured as an OpenID Connect client (RP)  of MyKeycloak (OP)
- ExternalIDP : an external IDP 
  MyKeycloak : keycloak realm configured with ExternalIDP as a brokering Identity Provider

MyApp delegate authentication to my MyKeycloak

MyKeycloak delegate authentication to ExternalIDP

Now, user go to ExternalIDP and logout. ExternalIDP need to call the back channel logout URL for each application client like MyKeycloak.

Where I can find this URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout/backchannel-logout`
ref: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#con-server-oidc-uri-endpoints_server_administration_guide

Answer (score 0):

The backchannel logout feature is located in the page `OpenID Connect settings/Advanced` of your external identity provider.
Activate the flag `Backchannel logout`.

Here an image to show exactly the location of the button
[image]

Comment: Hi, this option is to configure MyKeycloak but not how to configure ExternalIDP.
ExternalIDP need the back channel logout URL of MyKeycloak. 
I need this URL from MyKeycloak to give to ExternalIDP.
The question is "What is the back channel logout URL..."

Comment: @Franck I misunderstood the original question. I think that the keycloak URL for backchannel logout is the Admin URL that you set for your keycloak instance. To set this url check [this documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/hostname). For more information you could inspect the code of his [adapter](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/adapters/oidc/adapter-core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/PreAuthActionsHandler.java#L135)